# OR combinator not working in Java IF statement

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if (key != (VK_RIGHT || VK_DOWN)) //in this line bluej saying that's not correctly written. i want when the user is not pressing the down or up arrow it makes the error sound.
{
playSound("error");
}
```

i want when the user is not pressing the down or up arrow it makes the error sound. but in bluej it shows me that the || is not working.

Comment: As a future note: If you get an error (the code does not compile), please provide the **full error message** in your question. Then it is **way** easier for us to help.

Answer (score 6):

Because there is no short-cut syntax like that. And you want `&&` (not `||`).

```
if (key != VK_RIGHT && key != VK_DOWN)
```

The reason you don't want `or` is because those conditions will always be true (there is no key that is not RIGHT or not DOWN - that's all keys).

Answer (score 0):

"if key does not equal right or down" translates to: `key != VK_RIGHT && key != VK_DOWN`

"if key is not right or key is not down" translates to: `key != VK_RIGHT || key != VK_DOWN`